# Display Two Documents Side-By-Side with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am new to HTML and wish to do something that should be fairly simple.  I have searched for similar questions and tried the solutions, but none are working.

I want to display two documents in a web page side-by-side when a link is clicked.  The documents are stored remotely and are not static.  One is a PDF, the other is an image, so I feel the PDF may need to be embedded so there is a scroll bar?

Both documents are displaying, but the second document (image) partially lays over the first in the centre of the screen.

The code I have is as follows:

```
<a href= "#" onclick= "lightbox_open();"><b>Click me to view files</b></a>

<div id= "light"><a href= "#" onclick= "lightbox_close();"><embed src= "?php
echo $address ?>" style= "float: left;"/><img src = "<?php echo $address2 
?>" style= "float: left; " /></a></div>

<div id= "fade" onclick="lightbox_close();"></div>

<div>
```

**Note that the lightbox_open() and lighbox_close() functions are simply there to dim the screen when the screen when the documents are displayed.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)?

Comment: While this isn't a PHP question `?php
echo $address ?>` is an error. You also might want to look at modals I think it'd be easier using that and then styling.

Comment: I am extracting the remote addresses of the files using php code, therefore need the <?php echo $address ?> .

Comment: PM 77-1, use Bootstrap for debugging purposes?  I didn't think what I am trying to do would be so complex!!

Comment: don't float: left. set the widths to something like 45% and put some margin between them, like 10px. and set display: inline-block

Comment: may be it is due to size constraint. can you describe the dimensions and show some output?

Comment: I was suggesting Bootstrap as an easy to use tool for producing nicely aligned outputs on screens with different dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Source code is exactly same just replaced iframe with embed.

```css
<style> html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#doc1,
#doc2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  height: 100%
}
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}
#doc1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#doc2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body translate="no">

  <div id="doc1">
    <iframe src="http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf"></iframe>
  </div>

  <div id="doc2">
    <iframe src="http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**You Wont Be able to see the iframe here as the snippet in stackoverflow is inside a iframe already and iframe cannot be loaded inside another iframe.**

Comment: link is broken; please fix